# Android: Severe LAG in Canvas Spaceship 2D game, Need To Improve FPS, But How?

Tags: android, opengl-es, andengine, android-canvas, surfaceview

I am a near beginner at android programming, and i am currently making a spaceship game on canvas, where you can move the spaceship with your finger to dodge the oncoming asteroids.

Now, I have written the whole code on Canvas, on surface-View to be specific.

With four pictures, my game seems to be heavily lagging...

So is there some sort of a way to improve the Frames per second on my canvas, or would i have to use OpenGL, or some engine  to do that.

Below is my long code, if you see any way to improve FPS (frames per second), please tell me the code
Thanks

```
package com.zunairgames.zunair;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
 import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class GFXSurface extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

MyBringBackSurface ourSurfaceView;
float x, y;
boolean testingFinger=false;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ourSurfaceView = new MyBringBackSurface(this);
    ourSurfaceView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    x=0;
    y=0;

     requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,       WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(ourSurfaceView);//ourSurfaceView
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    ourSurfaceView.pause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    ourSurfaceView.resume();
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    x= event.getX();
    y= event.getY();

     if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
         testingFinger=true;
         return true;
     }
     if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
         testingFinger=false;
         return false;
     }



    return false;
}

public class MyBringBackSurface extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{
 //vertical
SurfaceHolder ourHolder;
Canvas canvas = (Canvas) ourHolder;
Thread ourThread = null;
boolean isRunning=false;
    int screenHeight;
    int screenWidth;

Random random = new Random ();
boolean loadStuff = false;

int posX=0;
int posY=0;
int posWidth=100;
int posHeight=100;


int numStars=4;
int starX[]=new int[numStars];
int starY[]=new int[numStars];
int starSpeed[]=new int[numStars];


int score=0;
int backgroundY=0;


Bitmap spaceship;
Bitmap background;
Bitmap starPic;


public MyBringBackSurface(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super(context);
    ourHolder= getHolder();


}

public void pause(){
    isRunning=false;
    while(true){
        try {
            ourThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
    }
    ourThread=null;
}
public void resume(){
    isRunning=true;
    ourThread=new Thread(this);
    ourThread.start();
}



public int round(double d){
    double dAbs = Math.abs(d);
    int i = (int) dAbs;
    double result = dAbs - (double) i;
    if(result<0.5){
        return d<0 ? -i : i;            
    }else{
        return d<0 ? -(i+1) : i+1;          
    }
}

public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
    int width = bm.getWidth();

    int height = bm.getHeight();

    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;

    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

    // create a matrix for the manipulation

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    // resize the bit map
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);   
    // recreate the new Bitmap

    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);

    return resizedBitmap;

    }
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    while(isRunning){
        if(!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid())continue;

         canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();

         if(loadStuff==false){
                for (int i=0; i <numStars; i++){
                    starY[i]=-random.nextInt(200);
                    starX[i]=random.nextInt(canvas.getWidth()-50);
                    starSpeed[i]=1+random.nextInt(5);
                }
                 spaceship =     BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.spaceship);
                 background  =     BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.background);
                 starPic  =     BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.tile);

                     backgroundY=-(canvas.getHeight());

                     x=canvas.getWidth()/2;
                     y=canvas.getHeight()/2;
                loadStuff=true;
                }


        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint.setTextSize(40);

        for (int i=0; i <numStars; i++){
            starY[i]+=starSpeed[i];

            if(starY[i]>canvas.getHeight()){
                starY[i]=-random.nextInt(200);
                starX[i]=random.nextInt(canvas.getWidth()-50);
                starSpeed[i]=starSpeed[i]+random.nextInt(2);
            }

            if(x+posWidth>starX[i]&&x<starX[i]+50 && y+posHeight>starY[i]&&y<starY[i]+50){
                starY[i]=-random.nextInt(200);
                starX[i]=random.nextInt(canvas.getWidth()-50);
                starSpeed[i]=1+random.nextInt(10);
                score++;
            }
        }

        backgroundY++;
        if(backgroundY>-10){
            backgroundY=-canvas.getHeight();
    }
        canvas.drawRGB( 3, 120, 12);
        canvas.drawBitmap(getResizedBitmap(background,(canvas.getHeight())*2,(canvas.getWidth())), 0,backgroundY, null);

        for (int i=0; i <numStars; i++){
              canvas.drawBitmap(getResizedBitmap(starPic,50,50),starX[i] , starY[i],null);

        }
        canvas.drawText("SCORE : "+ score ,(canvas.getWidth()/2) -80, 100, paint);





        canvas.drawBitmap(getResizedBitmap(spaceship,100,100), x,y, null);


        ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

    //72
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest performance mistake you are doing is:

```
 getResizedBitmap//This code is creating a new bitmap every time...
```

You are literally creating a new bitmap each render cycle and all this creation is running in the UI Thread, hence instead of doing that try to about bitmaps creation as much as possible, if the battleship and starPic is always the same, create the bitmap once during onCreate or in an "initialization" functionality, keep reference of that bitmap and making use of method:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, sourceBitmapRect, trasnlateRect, paint);
```

You can reuse an already existing bitmap and draw it in the screen in any position you want,
that will improve performance considerably, You don't need to use OpenGL for simple rendering games, i've developed couple of quiet complicated rendering games using this technique and works awesomely perfect as long as you are really careful on object creation and resources releasing...

Hope it helps

Regards!

Comment: Right general problem (bitmap creation in the loop), but those lines you pointed out aren't the problem. The `loadStuff` flag prevents this code from being executed every time.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the problem is the bitmap creation at getResizedBitmap

Comment: Great, that is working properly. Hey, i was just wondering about why my pictures sometimes are big on some phones and small on other phones...I am using Pixels to draw all pictures and shapes. Is there a simple way of fixing this?

Comment: Well, you should read about how to handle different densities on Android, see, the thing is that since you are drawing raw bitmaps on screen using canvas based on pixels, 10pxs on a low density device could cover a considerably amount of space, meanwhile 10pxs in high density devices could take a very small space, the idea is that your bitmaps should change based on device density, thats why you have drawable-ldpi/drawable-hdpi on your android project to set the proper images based on proper density...

Comment: Ooo. I think I get it, we will have to create a variable for each object, and then change it according to the density.That would create a lot of variables though, but Thanks

Comment: No, not really, actually android does it for you, if you refer to R.drawable.yourBMP, android will automatically take the proper asset from folder "drawable-somedensity", and it would do the trick, of course you have to set the proper image in the proper folder...

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `getResizedBitmap` in your main loop. You're creating and scaling new bitmaps every frame.

Comment: Great, that is working properly. Hey, i was just wondering about why my pictures sometimes are big on some phones and small on other phones...I am using Pixels to draw all pictures and shapes. Is there a simple way of fixing this?